# How to get DeepLens Device Name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-iot-greengrass, aws-deeplens

I have 3 deeplens devices running the same facial detection model. They send output to a certain s3 bucket which kicks off another lambda. However, I need one deeplens to send output to a separate s3 bucket. In order to do this I believe I need to get the deeplens device name.

Does anyone know how I can get the device name from within the greengrass lambda or some similar metadata to differentiate between devices?

Comment: I was looking for the exact same thing and finally managed to sort it out. You can access the Device name like this os.environ['AWS_IOT_THING_NAME'] Let me know if it helps!

Comment: yes, sorry. I actually managed to find the solution and posted it by editing my answer.